# Angular CDK Selection Model - issue with checkbox header states with paginated table

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

I am working on a paginated table with checkbox row selection using the angular CDK SelectionModel collection.

I have a barebones example with a couple of pages of data to flip between in my table and am facing a problem where after I select all rows on my first page using the checkbox header, when I go to the next page of data, the checkbox header remains checked even though my second page of rows are unchecked initially.

First Page

[image]

Second Page

[image]

You can see this in action at the following [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u6jqxc?file=src/main.ts)

It's easy to see why from my logic for setting the checkbox indeterminate state:

```
[checked]="this.selectionModel.selected.length > 0"
[indeterminate]="this.selectionModel.selected.length > 0 &&
                  this.selectionModel.selected.length < this.tableData.length"
```

After initially selecting all rows on the first page of data with the checkbox header and then navigating to the next page of data, `this.tableData.length` is still equal to `this.selectionModel.selected.length` and so the `[checked]` state evaluates to true since I still have items selected from the previous page.

What do I need to do here to ensure that as I flip between pages of data in my table, the checkbox header correctly reflects the state for the selections on the current page displayed, but also correctly reflects the indeterminate state?

I am sure I am missing something simple here, appreciate any help out there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the idea is the check everytime new data state you can check this solution :

```
 isAllNewDataSelected() {

return (
  this.tableData.filter((e) => this.selectionModel.isSelected(e.id))
    .length === this.tableData.length
);
```

}

```
newDataHasSelected() {
return (
  this.tableData.some((e) => this.selectionModel.isSelected(e.id)) &&
  this.tableData.filter((e) => this.selectionModel.isSelected(e.id))
    .length < this.tableData.length
);
```

}

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4v6wh2?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: Ah perfect, that makes sense, I knew it was somehow about comparing the loaded page of data with the selection model

Answer (score 0):

I think the problems comes in the condition of the `[checked]` you are checking if there are more than 0 selected fields but the conditions are overlaping. You have to add the opposite condition to ensure they never overlap.

```
                [checked]="
                  this.selectionModel.selected.length > 0 &&
                  this.selectionModel.selected.length < this.tableData.length
                "
                [indeterminate]="
                  this.selectionModel.selected.length > 0 &&
                  this.selectionModel.selected.length > this.tableData.length
                "
```

EDIT:
Demo on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qjgtbw.

Comment: That doesnt make any difference to the behaviour, if you think otherwise, please show me on the stackblitz

Comment: But it still does exactly the same thing as my original issue